# how to wait for many background jobs in bash

Tags: bash

How can I do parallel processing in bash?

My approach, in my bash script, added so many background jobs with `&`, and then I am adding each process id using an array, then I am fetching that array using a loop and inside that I am using wait command, but somehow `wait` command is not working.

### my code is like this

```
for i in some path 
do 
    ls -d $i | xargs du -kh --max-depth=0 |sed 's/\t/,/g' >> $TEMP/Outfile/disk_usage_Session_wise.csv & 
    pid=$!
    ls -d $i/session | xargs du -kh --max-depth=1 | sed 's/\t/,/g' >> $TEMP/Outfile/disk_usage_Session_wise.csv & 
    pid_1=$! 
    process_list=($pid $pid_1) 
done 

for job in echo ${process_list[@]} 
    do 
    echo "$job is running" 
    wait $job # this command is not working 
done –
```

Comment: When you say that `wait` is not working, what exactly do you mean?  Can you show some code that's not behaving as you expect and describe what you want it to do as opposed to what it's actually doing?

Comment: Have you considered a language with built-in parallel processing capabilities such as python or Perl ?

Comment: It would look better in your question.

Comment: @Tomas - thanks ..updated my question session . .i think now it looks good ..

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working" ?

Comment: it should wait for all background jobs to finish , instead of that script finished its execution without waiting for any background job to finish.

Comment: Your `process_list` array contains only the last two PIDs.

Comment: How to update it for all process id ?

Comment: you don't need the PIDs. `wait` without argument will wait for all background jobs to finish.

Comment: Per @lesmana - http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html *if n is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and the return status is zero.*

Comment: But wait command has to wait for only specific process id which are present in process_list array , but wait should not wait for all processes

Comment: Alex , yeah correct process_list contains only last two Pid , but how to update the array to contain all background processes ID

Answer (score 2):

Can you use additional software or only bash? Looks like `GNU Parallel` is what you need for your task. Or at least `-n` and `-P` arguments for `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

This improved line should fix the first part of your script:

```
process_list+=($pid $pid_1)
```

And this should be the second part. Notice it's not been tested.

```
for job in ${process_list[@]} 
do 
    ps -ho pid | >/dev/null grep $job && {
        echo "$job is running" 
        wait $job # this command should be ok now         
    }
done
```

- `ps -ho pid` produces a list of running processes (`-o pid`) without the heading line (`-h`).
- It forwards (`|`) this list to `grep`
- `grep` looks for the `$job` and if it finds it (`&&`), the block of commands (`{echo ...}`) is run

Comment: Can you explain what this line is doing ?
ps -ho pid | grep $job &&

Comment: @AshishSahoo see update

Comment: is it expected ? i am getting these error when i tried to run your comamnd
$ ps -ho pid | head
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ
  998

Comment: @AshishSahoo I added `>/dev/null` to keep it clean with regards to `grep`'s output.

Comment: @AshishSahoo No, that's unexpected. Please check for mistypes.

Comment: @AshishSahoo Check `ps -ho pid` only. If it's ok, it should be fine.

Comment: Still i am getting this error 
 ps -ho pid
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.7/FAQ
  998

Comment: @AshishSahoo Then your `ps` doesn't support it. Read `man ps` for how to produce a clean list of running processes.

Comment: @AshishSahoo Also try these two, which will be ok as well: `ps -o pid`, `ps -h -o pid`.

Comment: @AshishSahoo And if this one works, it will be even more simple after a rework: `ps -p <running process id>`. First run `ps` and find the pid of your shell, then insert it in place of `<running process id>`.